# Matplotlib: Histogram not showing in a subplot

Tags: python, matplotlib, histogram, subplot

I am new to matplotlib. I am trying to plot a histogram as a subplot below a scatterplot. This is the part of the code creating the plot -- CZs is a Pandas DataFrame whereas LinearRegression() is imported from sklearn.linear_model:

```
X= CZs.loc[(CZs.index != '38300') & (CZs.index != '38100'),  'pop1960_puma60'].as_matrix()
X.shape = (CZs.shape[0]-2,1)
y= CZs.loc[(CZs.index != '38300') & (CZs.index != '38100'), 'pop1960'].as_matrix()
zs = CZs.loc[(CZs.index != '38300') & (CZs.index != '38100'), 'pop_diff'].as_matrix()

model = LinearRegression()
model = LinearRegression(fit_intercept = False).fit(X,y)

xs1 = np.linspace(0, 100000000, 2)
ys1= xs1*model.coef_

fig, axs = plt.subplots(2, 1, tight_layout=True)
plt.ylim( (0, 12000000) )
plt.xlim( (0, 12000000) )
axs[0].scatter(xs, ys, c = 'red')
axs[0].plot(xs1, ys1, c = 'blue')
axs[0].set(xlabel='Pop. from Weights', ylabel='Exact Population', title='Weight Check')
axs[0].ticklabel_format(useOffset=False, style='plain')
axs[1].hist(zs)
axs[1].set(xlabel='Relative Error', ylabel='Frequency')
plt.savefig("subplots.png", dpi = 600)
```

The line

```
axs[1].hist(zs)
```

produces the following output

```
/conda_env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/numpy/lib/histograms.py:824: RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in greater_equal keep = (tmp_a >= first_edge)
/conda_env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/numpy/lib/histograms.py:825: RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in less_equal
(array([  1.,   1.,   4.,  30., 638.,  38.,   3.,   2.,   2. 1.]),array([-0.03605981, -0.02805883, -0.02005785, -0.01205688, -0.0040559 , 0.00394507,  0.01194605,  0.01994702,  0.027948  ,  0.03594898, 0.04394995]), <a list of 10 Patch objects>)
```

which I don't know how to interpret.

The figure produced is the following (sorry, I don't have the reputation to put the image inline):

wrong plot with empty histogram
[image]

As you can see the histogram subplot is empty.

However, if I plot the histogram on its own, the problem disappears. This code

```
zs = CZs.loc[(CZs.index != '38300') & (CZs.index != '38100'), 'pop_diff'].as_matrix()
fig, axs = plt.subplots(tight_layout=True)
axs.hist(zs)
axs.set(xlabel='Relative Error', ylabel='Frequency')
plt.savefig("hist.png", dpi = 600)
```

produces the same warnings, but also the expected histogram:

simple histogram as expected
[image]

What's going on? How can I modify the code so that it produces the two subplots?

Comment: Remove the line `plt.xlim( (0, 12000000) )`. Then you will get the two axes both showing their content. If then something else is not as you want it, you can ask specifically about that.

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest Thank you, it worked.  That was exactly the problem. I am still getting confused between the different kinds of sintax you can use in Matplotlib.